# include MySQL config file inside PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

I want to include MySQL config file inside PHP class.

```
<?php
class User {
    private $dbHost     = "localhost";
    private $dbUsername = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "";
    private $dbName     = "gic";
    private $userTbl    = 'users';

    function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->db)){
            // Connect to the database
            $conn = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }else{
                $this->db = $conn;
            }
        }
    }

    function checkUser($userData = array()){
        if(!empty($userData)){

            $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $host_upper = strtoupper($host);
            $path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
            $baseurl = "http://" . $host . $path ."/";


            $prevQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTbl." WHERE oauth_provider = '".$userData['oauth_provider']."' AND oauth_uid = '".$userData['oauth_uid']."'";
            $prevResult = $this->db->query($prevQuery);

           <!-- rest of my code --> 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this file, it's working fine, but I want to separate the MySQL database connection to another file (config.php), so I edited my code:

```
<?php
class User {

include 'config.php';

$connection = new createCon();
$conn = $connection->connect();

function checkUser($userData = array()){
    if(!empty($userData)){

        $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $host_upper = strtoupper($host);
        $path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $baseurl = "http://" . $host . $path ."/";


        $prevQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->userTbl." WHERE oauth_provider = '".$userData['oauth_provider']."' AND oauth_uid = '".$userData['oauth_uid']."'";
        $prevResult = $conn->query($prevQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

and config.php

```
<?php

class createCon  {
    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $user = 'root';
    var $pass = '';
    var $db = 'gic';
    var $myconn;

    function connect() {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect to database!');
        } else {
            $this->myconn = $con;
            echo 'Connection established!';}
        return $this->myconn;
    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($myconn);
        echo 'Connection closed!';
    }
}
?>
```

When I run the code above, it's showing an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gic001\User.php on line 4

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With inheritance, it should not be a big problem. Keep your config file as it is and try this.

```
include_once 'config.php';

class User extends createCon {

    private $conn;

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = $this->connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: @YourCommonSense OK. Tell me the problem with this answer (instead of imitating Darth Vader ;-)), so I can solve it and improve my answer.

Comment: you cannot improve it

Comment: @YourCommonSense OK. I got this.

Comment: luckily, I can close this duplicated question, so it won't make too much harm, advertising terrible practices and adding to the PHP's already bad reputation

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sure. May I ask you one thing? Did you use that facepalm image in your profile just because of these *bad* things? ;-)

Comment: yes, of course. if you look at PHP tag, 90% of answers here are asking for this picture

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the include outside of the class.

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class User {
```

Otherwise place it inside of a function:

```
class User {

 protected $conn;       


  public function __construct(){
    $this->loadConfig();
  }


  protected function loadConfig(){
     require('config.php');
     $connection = new createCon();
     $this->conn = $connection->connect();
  }
```

Also things you'll want to look into:

- [Try / Catch](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php) statements for catching the errors.
- [Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)
- [Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)
- [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: "Otherwise place it inside of a function." i didn't get ... can you please explain ?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: is my config.php file correct ? or need any changes

Comment: I would wrap it in a try/catch statement.

Comment: Nice alternative to extending connection class.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekAggrawal. I do something similar to this way to keep down the (memory) overhead and collisions that can happen with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, your whole approach is WRONG.

[**A user is not a database!**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#inheritance) There should never be such a property in the user class as a $dbHost. Neither it should ever bother to connect to the database. A user class should just use a connection defined elsewhere.

You should create a database instance, **once**. And then just pass it as a parameter to the user's constructor method

```
class User {
    protected $conn;
    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
    function checkUser($userData = array()){
        $prevResult = $this->conn->query($prevQuery);
    }
}
```

so just include your credentials once, just where the connection is created.